# Am I mixing up the concept of posts pages and categories?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, pages

I'm planning on having workshops on this layout:

[image: screenshot]

I have several workshops: Meditation has 2 or 3, Reikki has 2 and Feng Shui has a couple.

So as I read the codex about pages and categories I get a bit confused.

Should I create a category called Workshops, put it on the menu, then create a Meditation page, and on that page put the events as posts? And is it possible to showcase the indivdual workshops in the sidebar like I show in the image above? Note that I plan to have a "Recent Articles" on a sidebar below "Workshops", not sure if that will interfere.

This may be a basic concept but the more I think about this, the more my head hurts.

P.S.: I have 2 workshops repeated in the screenshot, just for the sake of visualization.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) may be of use. `Workshop` could be a custom post type, categorized by a [Custom Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) `Workshop Type`.

You would add a workshop post in a separate admin section, and assign a type. This then allows you to easily list workshops independently of other content.

You are then free to use the default posts post type for things like news and general blog types of content.

Comment: If I create a custom post type "Workshops" that would list all the posts I categorize as "Workshops", then if someone hovers the Workshop on the menu it will list ALL the workshops I have? They won't have a distinction (Reikki, Feng Shui, Yoga) then? I would have to create their respective custom post types for each and assign them to the main custom post type, ie, Workshops?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I'm confused about using posts or pages I ask my self: Does my content change regularly or not? If it does then use posts, if it doesn't use pages.

In your case I would think of it in the way that you **always** offer workshops for Meditation, Reikki and Feng Shui. So any general information about these workshops belong to pages such as `/workshops/feng-shui/` where static info about what you are offering would go.

However, everything that is likely to change often, for example workshop sessions at a certain date, would go into a post such as "How to Medidate Workshop (June 11)" where you would only display information that is unique to this one event ("We meet at the gate at 8pm", "bring your own footwear", "This workshop is for for advanced trainees only"). From there you can link to your pages that offer general information about the workshop. You aren't limited to event postings though: you could blog about frequently asked questions during a recent workshop too or show a picture gallery or announce news.

Finally you would create categories according to your workshops that you use to pull related posts into your pages. For example on your meditations info page you would have sidebar widget showing "related articles to meditations" that display the latest 5 posts categorized in meditations ordered by date. The ways you can do this with WordPress are endless.

Answer (score 0):

- You can imagine **categories** a simply a bundling of **posts** that
  belong together.
- While **pages** usually contain 'static information', **posts** are usually 'actualities', with information that is more time-sensitive.
- **Posts** often carry additional information over **pages**, such as time post was published, who posted it and in which category it belongs. **Pages** usually don't show this data because that is not their intended purpose.

Since it looks like your workshop idea is time-sensitive, and each individual workshop could be seen as an "event" that only occurs once in time, you should create a category *Workshops* in which you create posts for every workshop.

> and on that page put the events as posts?

One of your misconceptions here may be that you need to create a separate **Page** on which you can display an entire **category**. This is redundant, because WordPress supports what is called Category Pages. These type of pages are automagically generated if your theme has a `category.php` template. The category page for *Workshops* would already contain all workshop events; you don't have to create a page for that.